# Module Not Found Error with one version of of Python, but no the other

Tags: python, linux

I am using a VS Code (Linux Mint) plug-in for Python that allows me to choose between different interpreters.

When I run my file with Python 3.8, I get an error saying that it can't find pandas I am trying to use, but when I switch the interpreter to Python 3.6 there is no issue finding pandas.

What's going on?

Comment: Check the docs. You might be running each interpreter in its own virtual environment (meaning it has access only to modules installed in that environment).  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 0):

The module might not be updated for Python 3.8. Search up the module's name from GitHub or where it can be imported from to see what versions they support.

Comment: It was the pandas module.

Answer (score 0):

That module isn't installed for Python 3.8, simple as that. Different versions of Python have different libraries (listed under `sys.path`) on Debian-based distros.

Without knowing which module, it's hard to say much else, like whether it even supports 3.8, but to install it, you might be able to use `apt` or `pip`.

Comment: It was the pandas module

Comment: @ElGallo Ah yeah, I don't think Pandas is packaged for APT. You can use `pip` to install it.